# Setup server level monitoring and alerting for Splunk Forwarder, Indexer and Search Head

Tags: linux, monitoring, splunk

I want to setup server level monitoring and alerting for Splunk Forwarders, Indexers and Search Heads to monitor and alert if there are issues related to vCPU, RAM, Memory etc. from Linux command line.
Also I want to monitor from Linux command the version of Splunk forwarder/Splunk Enterprise along with other details like if log ingestion and log distribution is working properly or if there are any issues with other servers in a distributed environment.
Can someone please help.
Please note: I do not have access to Splunk GUI, I can only access these servers through Linux command line like a Splunk Admin.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Splunk has many dashboards to show that information, most of which are in the Monitoring Console (MC) app.  This is how Splunk Admins monitor their deployment.  To access the information from the command line would require replicating the searches in the MC, submitting them to Splunk for processing, and parsing the results.

The command to show the version of Splunk is `$SPLUNK_HOME/bin/splunk version`.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to access this information from command line, replicate the searches, submit them to Splunk for processing, create alerts and parse the result?

Comment: To replicate the searches in the MC you will need access to the GUI.  Some can be found from the command line in $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/apps/splunk_monitoring_console/default/savedsearches.conf, but many are only visible in the GUI.
The method for performing searches from the CLI is too complex to explain here, but uses the REST API or Splunk's SDK.  You can read about the former at https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.6/RESTTUT/RESTsearches